# Unexpected Behavior of tri1 with multiple driver

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am getting unexpected behavior with nested interface, tri1 net and assignments from class/module.

Here is the code.

---

```
interface i2c ();
  tri1 sda;
  logic sda_out;

  assign sda = sda_out;
endinterface

interface dev ();
  i2c i();
endinterface

class a;
  virtual interface dev d;

  task run1();
    $display("@%0t : Entering run1 a", $time());
    d.i.sda_out = 1'b0;
    #2; 
    d.i.sda_out = 1'bz;
    #2;
    $display("@%0t : Leaving run1 a", $time());
  endtask
endclass

module b (inout x);
  logic y;

  assign x = y;

  initial begin
    #4;
    y = 1'bz;
    #2;
    y = 1'b0;
  end
endmodule

module temp();
  dev d();
  b b1 (d.i.sda);
  a a1 = new();


  initial begin
    a1.d = d;
    a1.run1();
  end

  always_comb
    $display ("@%0t : d.i.sda - %0b, d.i.sda_out - %0b", $time(), d.i.sda, d.i.sda_out);
endmodule
```

---

Here is the output with b1 commented and uncommented.

---

```
// With b1 commented

@0 : Entering run1 a
@0 : d.i.sda - x, d.i.sda_out - 0
@0 : d.i.sda - 0, d.i.sda_out - 0
@2 : d.i.sda - 0, d.i.sda_out - z
@2 : d.i.sda - 1, d.i.sda_out - z
@4 : Leaving run1 a



// With b1 uncommented

@0 : Entering run1 a
@0 : d.i.sda - x, d.i.sda_out - 0
@2 : d.i.sda - x, d.i.sda_out - z
@4 : Leaving run1 a
@4 : d.i.sda - 1, d.i.sda_out - z
@6 : d.i.sda - 0, d.i.sda_out - z
```

---

**Since tri1 is like wire with pullups, shouldn't it allow multiple driver?**

Because when b1 is uncommented, the assign statement for sda seems not to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` is X at time 0. You don't assign it to Z until `#4`. X will cause contention on the bus.

Initializing `y` to Z at time zero will resolve the contention.

```
initial begin
  y = 1'bz;
  #6;
  y = 1'b0;
end
```